# Error from Ksplice cron job

Tags: 11.10, cron, dbus

I'm running Ksplice on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and I get the following error when the Ksplice cron job runs.

```
$export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin && [ -x /usr/sbin/uptrack-upgrade ] && /usr/sbin/uptrack-upgrade --cron
GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

When I run the command manually as root I get no output and a return value of 0.

Does anyone know a fix or if this error can just be ignored?